# Need to send a .csv to Teams using Powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I want to send a .csv file to Microsoft Teams channel using Powershell. I have the incoming webhook URI but I am not sure which command should I use to accomplish this. I've tried using the `SendTeamsMessage` command but couldn't get through.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you. And this forum rocks..

Comment: Please add more information

Comment: I have a server which uses powershell script to send a .csv file (which is an output file) to an email and I need to change it to send it to Microsoft Teams channel instead of email. First thing which I did was to create a connector in the Teams channel and copy https link. Now I am trying to find a way/commands in PS to send the file and where I need help. Would you need further details?

Comment: Please look at [Send and receive files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-and-receive-files?tabs=dotnet)

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below script, it is working

```
Send-MailMessage -From "User1@contoso.com" -To "channelemailaddress" -Subject "Test123" -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" -Credential "User1@contoso.com" -UseSsl -Attachments "E:\scripts\output.csv"
```

Please refer the attached document for more info. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. But thank you for your reply. The one which you posted is for sending an email to a recipient. I want to send a file to a channel in Microsoft Teams.

Comment: You can send email to your channel. Could you please look into this [How to find Channel email address](https://melihubb.com/2017/07/18/how-to-find-your-microsoft-teams-channel-email-address/)?